# Azure ServiceConfiguration schema issue

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-compute-emulator

I'm using the azure plugin for eclipse to package 5 compute services. Deploying 1 works just fine but when I added the other 4 I got the following error. Note, I am not editing any xml manually.

Error:

```
C:\public\deploy\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg(48,2) : Error : Error CloudService 51 : The element 'ServiceConfiguration' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration' has invalid child element 'Role'......
```

I followed the auzure eclipse plugin instructions to download the latest SDK so I want to rule out a version mismatch there. What could be going on here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that all the roles need to be listed in sequence in the XML. I had a NetworkConfiguration node in the middle which was causing the issue. Move it to the end.

The overall structure of configuration file has to be as mentioned at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee758710.aspx).

Comment: OMG..after struggling the same issue ,googling found no answer and at last landed here with answer of zero upvotes. applied the suggestion with heavy heart and no expectation...but wow..the issue resolved. Thank you ..upvote one from me.